# Connecting private load balancer to cloud front distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, amazon-cloudfront

I have a python flask application hosted on Elastic Beanstalk (Private Load Balancer).

I wanted to integrate Elastic Beanstalk with Cloudfront so that the Web application can be opened using cloudfront distribution.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can create distribution in CF with Load Balancer as an Origin and map the DNS to the CF distribution.

Comment: @Chetan will this work with private load balancer?

Comment: You can't do that. ALB must be public.

Comment: @Marcin hope your doing well. It's been a long time. 
Can this be achieved?

Comment: Hi. No it cannot be achieve. ALB must be public.

Comment: @Marcin  
https://github.com/Wolox/tech-guides/blob/master/infrastructure/docs/aws/docs/cloudfront-eb-configuration.md

This link must be talking about public load balancer?

Comment: Yes, its public.

Comment: @Marcin any documents that i can referee to where it shows that cloudfront doesn't work with private load balancer ?

Comment: @Marcin can you have a look at this? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74460296/best-way-to-make-content-on-internal-private-lb-available-to-public/74461998#74461998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALB must be public. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html):

> Although you can use a signed URL to distribute content from a custom origin, for CloudFront to access the custom origin, the origin **must remain publicly** accessible.