# Best way to make content on internal/private LB available to public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an application which is running a flask component with the help of elasticbeanstack set up the infrastructure.

The LB is private a LB present in private subnet.

Now, what I want to do is make the connect securely available publicly.

What would be the best option to integrate it?

Having LB(public) -> NAT(Public) - > LB(private) feels to much of moving component.

Comment: As the answer states, ALB must be in public subnet.

Comment: @Marcin could you help me out with this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220145/props-source-bindasnotificationrulesource-is-not-a-function-in-aws-cdk-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a ALB in a public subnet, and point it to your instances. Allow traffic from the public subnet in your application instances' security group. Essentially a [public/private setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html#services-vpc-privatepublic).

Comment: any other options?