# props.source.bindAsNotificationRuleSource is not a function in aws cdk python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-cdk

I am trying to set up notification to my codepipeline in aws.
Been following this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_codestarnotifications/README.html

```
pipeline = CodePipeline(
            self,
            id,
            pipeline_name=id,
            synth=synth_step,
            cross_account_keys=True,
            code_build_defaults=pipelines.CodeBuildOptions(
                build_environment=BuildEnvironment(
                    build_image=aws_codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0,
                    privileged=True,
                )
            ),
        )
```

after creating my code pipeline with in the stack i am creating a notification rule.

```
rule = aws_codestarnotifications.NotificationRule(self, "NotificationRule",
            source=pipeline,
            events=["codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-failed", "codepipeline-pipeline-pipeline-execution-succeeded"
            ],
            targets=[sns_topic]
        )
```

but i am getting `RuntimeError: props.source.bindAsNotificationRuleSource is not a function`.

I also tried solution mentioned here, but didn't workout.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9710

Does anyone has an idea on it? where am i going wrong?

Comment: saw your comment on github.. and it has a diff error to this? **AttributeError: 'CodePipeline' object has no attribute 'buildPipeline**

Comment: @Kulasangar That is when i try the method mentioned in the github

Comment: This is a dependency issue. What's the output of `pip freeze`?  You probably have mismatched CDK dependencies. Any reason you're using the deprecated CDK v1?

Comment: @gshpychka i am using 2.6

Comment: That version is over a year old. Can you add the output of `pip freeze`? Maybe you also have v1 in there.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @gshpychka not yet completely.

Comment: Can you add the output of `pip freeze` to the question?

Comment: Please don't abandon your questions.

Answer (score 1):

These two things fixed the problem for me:

1. have `pipeline.build_pipeline()` before defining the notification rule
2. defining `source` as `pipeline.pipeline`

This assumes that `pipeline` is a `pipelines.CodePipeline` object (vs `aws_codepipeline.Pipeline`)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with

```
source=pipeline,
```

Here the source in notification rule is expecting an pipeline ARN.
As we are working with CDK we need to make sure the pipeline is built before we set up the notification stack.

To over come this we need to build the pipeline and then set up the notification rule.

Use `pipeline.build_pipeline()` after pipeline and before notification rule code.

This worked for me.
also please refer [active thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9710) for detailed explanation.